# BitBucket - pushing code to staging & production servers

Tags: bitbucket

I'm currently transitioning from SVN to GIT, specifically BitBucket for our repos.

I've seen a handful of articles via Google talking about how to setup githooks / BitBucket services to automatically push commits to BitBucket out to remote servers. and if I'm reading it all correctly, this is all about automatically pushing out these updates to the remote servers.

I want to be able to control the push to our remote servers, especially the production server, as we want to control when changes are made rather than assume everything committed is production ready.

Am I missing the plot and something obvious in how to make this happen? My goal would be to virtually eliminate the need to setup FTP access to the staging & production servers for other team members, but still allow code to be pushed to these in a controlled manner.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this post:

http://lkwdwrd.com/git-auto-deployment/

This is not your actual requirement. But with a little efforts with PHP you can make your push to be selective.

An expected solution will be store each payload in database as a queue and deploy complete queue payloads(and empty the queue) when required.